# How to create a file containing info from another file?

Tags: permissions, files

I am trying to create a file contating the info from my /etc/passwd file but can not seem to get it to work. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You might want to provide some specifics. What is it that you are *exactly* trying to do?

Comment: Question too vague to be meaningful.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to use cp then you may try this from the location where you created filepassword;

cat "/etc/passwd" >> filepassword

Will append the contents of file /etc/passwd to file, filepassword, hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

1. Click **Places** ▸ **Computer** and then browse to **File System** ▸ **etc**.
2. Drag **passwd** to the desktop:

   [image: screenshot]

You now have a copy of `/etc/passwd` that you are free to edit and rename.

Answer (score 2):

In this instance, the correct command would be `cp /etc/passwd /path/to/file/you/want/to/save/to` - for other files, you can drop the sudo.

Comment: I created a file called "filepassword" and now want it to contain the info from /etc/passwd file.

Comment: Yeah, a straight copy seems like it's what you want.

Comment: Alright. So in that case, it'd be `sudo cp /etc/passwd ~/filepassword' - your file would be found in your home directory.

Comment: `sudo` is not required here.